# python triply nested for loop code optimization

Tags: python, numpy, performance, loops, optimization

I have written a code which has its bottleneck in a triply-nested for-loop which goes through the 3-dimensional Physical space (r,  theta, phi).

[The code has to work on each of the datapoints from this 3D space, so there is no clever way to re-design the logic in order to avoid the triply-nested for loop.]

This triply nested for-loop will be called in the main code 8825 times (potentially more).
It is allowed to only use 1 core.
I need to make it as fast as possible.
I can now get it to work in 14 - 15 seconds.

Please, do you see any other improvements I could make?

- I have tried to minimize brute computations. I.e. avoid repeatedly calling `np.sin` , `np,cos`, etc, and pre-compute these calculations' results inside pre-allocated arrays. I then just index these numpy arrays I created before.
- I have found a function which is O(n * log n) to search through a sorted array.

A MWE is (edit, I now know, due to @JonSG, that the `np.imag(conhyp_results[k_idx, :, 0])` factor can be taken outside the triply nested-for loop):

```
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter


Nb = 300
l_max = 50
Z = 1.0

def Coulomb(r):
    return (-Z / r)

def find_idx_closest_to_input(array, target_value):
    # it assumes array is sorted and is 1 dimensional
    n = array.shape[0]
    if (target_value < array[0]):
        return -1
    elif (target_value > array[n-1]):
        return n

    jl = 0 # Initialize lower
    ju = n-1 # and upper limits.

    while (ju-jl > 1): # If we are not yet done,

        jm = (ju+jl) >> 1 # compute a midpoint with a bitshift
        if (target_value >= array[jm]):
            jl = jm # and replace either the lower limit
        else:
            ju = jm # or the upper limit, as appropriate.
        # Repeat until the test condition is satisfied.

    if (target_value == array[0]): # edge cases at bottom
        return 0
    elif (target_value == array[n-1]): # and top
        return n-1
    else:
        return jl

coulomb_array = np.random.rand( Nb )

ris = np.random.rand( Nb )
sin_thetas = np.random.rand( l_max+1 )
cos_thetas = np.random.rand( l_max+1 )
sin_phis = np.random.rand( 2*l_max+2 )
cos_phis = np.random.rand( 2*l_max+2 )
r_vec_cartesian = np.zeros ( (3) )
b_vec = np.random.rand ( 3 )
b_dot_vec = np.random.rand ( 3 )

k_vec_cartesian = np.random.rand ( 3 )
k_wave = 2.0
conhyp_results = np.random.rand( 15, 10000, 2 ) + 1j * np.random.rand( 15, 10000, 2 ) 

Psi_scattering_prelim = np.zeros ( ( Nb, (l_max+1), (2*l_max+2) ) ) + 1j * np.zeros ( ( Nb, (l_max+1), (2*l_max+2) ) )
tensor_of_exp_of_minusI_bdot_times_r = np.zeros ( (Nb, (l_max+1), (2*l_max+2)) ) + 1j * np.zeros ( (Nb, (l_max+1), (2*l_max+2)) )
difference_in_potential_values = np.zeros( (Nb, (l_max+1), (2*l_max+2)) )

k_idx = 10

prefactor = 10.0

t_coordinates_start = perf_counter()
for a in range(Nb):
    for b in range(l_max+1):
        for c in range(2*l_max+2):
            r_vec_cartesian[0] = ris[a] * sin_thetas[b] * cos_phis[c]
            r_vec_cartesian[1] = ris[a] * sin_thetas[b] * sin_phis[c]
            r_vec_cartesian[2] = ris[a] * cos_thetas[b]                 
            r_minus_b_vec_cartesian = r_vec_cartesian - b_vec
            r_minus_b_vec_cartesian_modulus = np.sqrt( r_minus_b_vec_cartesian.dot(r_minus_b_vec_cartesian) )

            arg3_imag_part = -( k_wave*r_minus_b_vec_cartesian_modulus + k_vec_cartesian.dot(r_minus_b_vec_cartesian) ) # a np.float64


            index_from_conhyp_results = find_idx_closest_to_input( np.imag(conhyp_results[k_idx, :, 0]), arg3_imag_part )

            result_cpp = conhyp_results[k_idx, index_from_conhyp_results, 1]
            
            factor = np.exp( 1j * k_vec_cartesian.dot(r_minus_b_vec_cartesian) )
            Psi_scattering_prelim[a, b, c] = prefactor * factor * result_cpp
            b_dot_vec_times_r_vec = b_dot_vec.dot(r_vec_cartesian)
            tensor_of_exp_of_minusI_bdot_times_r[a, b, c] = np.exp(-1j * b_dot_vec_times_r_vec)

            difference_in_potential_values[a, b, c] = coulomb_array[a] - Coulomb(r_minus_b_vec_cartesian_modulus)
# END for loop through coordinates

t_coordinates_end = perf_counter()
print("We have gone through the coordinates")
print("To go through coordinates it took: " + str(t_coordinates_end - t_coordinates_start) + " seconds")
```

It shall run in ~ 15 seconds.

Ideally, if one made it to work in < 8-9-10 seconds, it would be great.

I do not want to use numba becauase this part of the code is inside a much bigger project.

Thank you!

Comment: _there is no clever way to re-design the logic in order to avoid the triply-nested for loop_ - I beg to differ. That's what vectorisation is for.

Comment: _It is allowed to only use 1 core_ - why? This seems arbitrary and somewhat difficult to enforce when using a high-performance library

Comment: @Reinderien, this is because this triply-nested for loop is called 8825 times, each time inside another triply-nested for loop (which I aim to parallelize with MPI across the cores). basically I have for x in range() : for y in range() : for z in range() : for t in range(8825) : call_triply_nested_for_loop(). also, I do not know if the .dot() operations on (3,) shaped vectors (1D arrays) gain anything from a threaded-blas implementation?

Comment: Read some introductory material, perhaps https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/#what-is-vectorization

Comment: @Reinderien, thanks for the info, I will read! ``there is no clever way to re-design the logic in order to avoid the triply-nested for loop`` : I mean, the code has to go through those iterations. In which order, how, vectorised, non-vectorised, that's why my question is about ...

Comment: This code is very complicated. Since you just learnt about vectorization it may be too much for you. I would suggest going for `numba` package. Not easy too, but except fixing some "not-compatible-for-numba" parts, the code will stay almost the same.

Comment: You can shave a few seconds off by moving parts of the inner most loop out side to where they become static.  For example `np.imag(conhyp_results[k_idx, :, 0])` has a fixed value before you even start the outer most loop. Doing that makes it run in 11.5 seconds for me. You can also quick return from `find_idx_closest_to_input()` without doing the while loop if you find `target_value` compared tot he start and end of the`array` is certain things.

Comment: @JonSG, thank you. I totally missed the ``np.imag(conhyp_results[k_idx, :, 0])`` part.

Comment: just curious, your code is in no way vectorized. startinf rom a simple `find` function, python already has a `np.searchsorted` function. Why write yours yet the one in python is optimized and vectorized?

Comment: Seems most of work you are doing can be vectorized. Probably you should consider posting an image of the function you are computing and see whether someone will help you out with a vectorized version of your code. One thing i can clearly change is to use `np.searchsorted(array, targets)` where targets ia another array. This is magnitudes faster than your code. Your code only takes one target at a time, while the `np.searchsorted` takes an array of values as target and returns an array of values

Comment: A search for the closest point  in low dimensional (3d) is usullay the field of a kd-tree search. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html If you can transform the problem to a simple nearest neighbour search (x,y,z) beforehand.

Comment: Is it solved with the transformation to usr kd-trees? It does look like a small problem where eg. a Numba implementation without changing the algorithm can be some orders of magnitude faster than the provided example.

Comment: @max9111, thank you, but I honestly do not understand what you refer to / how is it helpful to my case. could you please elaborate a bit on it?